# Split this array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of cities and ID's looking like:

```
Brønderslev|810,Frederikshavn|813,Hjørring|860,Jammerbugt|849,Læsø|825,Mariagerfjord|846,Morsø|773,Rebild|840,Thisted|787,Vesthimmerland|820,Aalborg|851
```

I **do not** want this:

```
<option value="810">Frederikshavn</option>
```

I **do** want this:

```
<option value="813">Frederikshavn</option>
```

The commas separate the key/value *pairs* and the pipes separate the keys from the values.

I've come this far, however it doesnt seem to loop ?

```
//Get cities by Region
```

function GetCitiesByRegion(args) {

```
var params = '{"regionGuid":"' + args + '"}'

var request = {
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "http://" + location.hostname + "/webservices/services.svc/GetCitiesByRegion",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: params,
    success: function (result) {
        //alert("Data Loaded: " + result.d);
        var resultData = result.d;
        alert(resultData);
        $jq.each(resultData.split('|'), function (city, value) {
           //alert(this);
           alert(city + ': ' + value);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Fejl ved webservice: error: ' + error);
    }
};

$jq.ajax(request);
```

}

Comment: Who designed the web service and why are they using JSON but *not* using JSON at the same time?

Comment: That's not a valid array! What datatype is it - String?

Comment: Nicky, I've edited your question to make it more clear about what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will transform your string to `option` elements:

```
$.each(str.split(","), function(k, v) {
    var v = v.split("|");
    $("<option />").text(v[0]).val(v[1]).appendTo("select");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XRD6Y/

Comment: better add `select#id` , otherwise OP will have all the select elements in page filled with garbage ;)

Comment: This will *not* work. This will result in <option value="813">Frederikshavn</option>. The wrong number will be put with the name because you looped on the comma first and the pipe second. Also, you are overwriting "v" with "var v".

Comment: @mawcsco How come? Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/XRD6Y/1/. The author most probably has a typo in the question. "Frederikshavn" should have 813 as a value, otherwise pairs does not make any sense.

Comment: @mawcsco The Notation of the separated Values states VisioN is correct, though the OP has another value in the example option - probably a typo.

Comment: Yeah, look at the result of your code, you get: <option value="810">Brønderslev</option>.  This is not the result that the OP was looking for, they wanted: <option value="810">Frederikshavn</option>

Comment: @Christoph, the OP wants to split sets of key/value pairs. The pairs are separated by a pipe, the key and value are separated by a comma.

Comment: @NickyChristensen I believe that is because `result.d` is not a string.

Comment: @NickyChristensen: Post better information in your question, and you'll get better answers. If this answer doesn't do what you want, then you've misrepresented something.

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood this: "How do i loop and then split it to fx" This question is poorly written.

Comment: Dont mind, I got it to work with tweaking the example from @VisioN

Answer (score 0):

You requested a JSON format, which is *not* a string.

Therefore you can't use `split()` to change that to text/html.